# VLC Crashing when loading any video

Tags: linux, video, crash, vlc

When trying to open any video in my Linux distro, be it an mp4 file or movie ISO, VLC would immediately crash. None of the current resources online helped my case. Does anyone have any fixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this myself by checking which window server I was using, which would be X11. Then in VLC I went to `Tools` > `Preferences` > `Video` and then changed `Output` to `X11 video output (XCB)`. This solved my video issues.

Comment: Did the trick for me (with setting XVideo).